# Is it a Markov process?

Tags: probability, markov-process

Consider the random variable $S_t:= x+ t-\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$,
where $X_i \in \mathbb{N}_0$ and i.i.d.
Can I state that I deal with a Markov process here?

Comment: Have you checked whether it satisfies the definition of a Markov process? (And if you are having trouble doing so, where are you stuck?)

Comment: @angryavian: I have to check that $S_{t+1} $ only depends on the value which $S_t$ takes. But it doesn't depend on anything because the $X_i$ are i.i.d. Where do I make a mistake?

Comment: The $X_i$ are independent but the $S_t$ are not because they are defined in terms of some of the same $X_i$'s.

Comment: I thought the sum of i.i.d random variables is i.i.d?

Comment: What does "the sum is i.i.d." mean? "i.i.d." means "independent and identically distributed". The sum is independent from what? The sum is identically distributed to what?

Comment: @MishaLavrov: I mean $X_1+X_2$ is independent to $X_1+X_2+X_3$

Comment: Is that right? $S_{t+1}$ only depends on $S_t$ because of the term $x+t$ Did I get that right?

Comment: No, that's not right. I will say more in an answer.

Comment: ok thank you very much:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you mean $S_t = x + t - \sum_{i=1}^t X_i$, not $\sum_{i=1}^n$. The conclusion is the same either way, but the sum going up to $t$ makes more sense as a process to look at.

We pick the sequence $X_1, X_2, X_3, \dots$ independently from whichever distribution they're drawn from, but we only do it once. So two partial sums like $X_1 + X_2$ and $X_1 + X_2 + X_3$ are not independent. For example:

- $\Pr[X_1 + X_2 = 1]$ and $\Pr[X_1 + X_2 + X_3 = 0]$ can in general be positive probabilities, assuming that the $X_i$ distribution can be $0$ or $1$ with positive probability.
- If the two sums were independent, then $\Pr[X_1 + X_2 = 1 \text{ and } X_1 + X_2 + X_3 = 0]$  would also be a positive probability: the product of the two probabilities above.
- However, $\Pr[X_1 + X_2 = 1 \text{ and } X_1 + X_2 + X_3 = 0]$ must be $0$, since $X_1+X_2=1$ and $X_1+X_2+X_3=0$ together imply that $X_3 = -1$.

---

For your random process, we have $S_{t+1} - S_t = 1 - X_{t+1}$, because the other terms all cancel in the difference. This means that, given $S_t$, everything about $S_{t+1}$ is determined entirely by $X_{t+1}$.

This should let you check the definition of a Markov process and conclude that this sequence is one.

Comment: Thank you for answer. But I can state that $\sum_{i=1}^{t}X_i$ is independent from $X_{t+1}$?

Comment: Yes, because $(X_1, \dots, X_t)$ are independent from $X_{t+1}$, and $\sum_{i=1}^t X_i$ is a function of $(X_1, \dots, X_t)$. The difference is that there are no random variables in common on both sides.

Comment: Thank you. Your example was really helpful:) I do not understand why you consider the difference between $S_t$ and $S_{t+1}$. I only have to ensure that $P(S_{t+1 }=k_{t+1}| S_t=k_t,...S_1=k_1)=P(S_{t+1 }=k_{t+1}| S_t=k_t)$

Comment: The difference helps me see that $S_{t+1}$ only depends on the earlier terms via $S_t$; if you are happy checking this condition directly, then that's also fine.

Comment: That is the problem. I can really check this defintion. How would you go on from your point of view?

Comment: Well, if you write $S_{t+1} = S_t + 1 -X_{t+1}$, then $\Pr[S_{t+1} = k_{t+1} \mid S_t = k_t, \dots]$ becomes $\Pr[X_{t+1} = 1 + k_t - k_{t+1} \mid S_t = k_t, \dots]$, and $X_{t+1}$ is independent of all of those.

Comment: Thank you very much:)

Comment: But $X_{t+1}$ is also independent of $S_t$ ?

Comment: Yes, so both $\Pr[S_{t+1}=k_{t+1} \mid S_t =k_t, \dots, S_1=k_1]$ and $\Pr[S_{t+1}=k_{t+1}\mid S_t = k_t]$ simplify to $\Pr[X_{t+1}=1-k_t-k_{t+1}]$, which is how we know that they're equal.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry for the further question :(